# How can I import data from ASCII (ISO/IEC 8859-1) to my Rails/PGSQL database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, import

I am trying to use data from the USDA found here: http://www.ars.usda.gov/Services/docs.htm?docid=23634

> ASCII (8.6Mb) - This file contains the SR26 data in ASCII (ISO/IEC 8859-1), delimited files. These tables are organized in a relational format, and are best used with a relational database management system (RDBMS), which will allow you to form your own queries of the database and generate custom reports.

I am new to manipulating data like this and think I would like to get it in CSV, maybe? But, then I might lose the relationships so maybe I should go right to PGSQL.  Not sure how to approach this.

Looking for guidance, thanks.

Comment: had the exact same question for the exact same database :p

Comment: I came here for the exact same question :P they probably are the only ones using this uncommon format

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The zip contains a number of files:

```
  inflating: DATA_SRC.txt            
  inflating: DATSRCLN.txt            
  inflating: DERIV_CD.txt            
  inflating: FD_GROUP.txt            
  inflating: FOOD_DES.txt            
  inflating: FOOTNOTE.txt            
  inflating: LANGDESC.txt            
  inflating: LANGUAL.txt             
  inflating: NUT_DATA.txt            
  inflating: NUTR_DEF.txt            
  inflating: sr26_doc.pdf            
  inflating: SRC_CD.txt              
  inflating: WEIGHT.txt
```

each of which appears to be in a bizarre almost-CSV-like format, e.g. `NUTR_DEF.txt`:

```
~287~^~g~^~GALS~^~Galactose~^~2~^~2100~
~291~^~g~^~FIBTG~^~Fiber, total dietary~^~1~^~1200~
```

plus `sr26_doc.pdf`, the documentation.

### Creating table definitions

So what you need to do here is create SQL table definitions for the database - with one table for each input file. You need the `CREATE TABLE` command for this; see the PostgreSQL documentation.

Page 35 of the PDF should help you - "Figure 1. Relationships among files in the USDA National Nutrient Database for Standard Reference". The following pages describe the file formats, telling you what each column means. You can write `CREATE TABLE` statements based on this description.

Here's an example, for `FOOD_DES.txt` (food description), the first entry.

```
CREATE TABLE food_des (
    "NDB_No"      varchar(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "FdGrp_Cd"    varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    "Long_Desc"   varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    "Shrt_Desc"   varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    "ComName"     varchar(100),
    "ManufacName" varchar(65),
    "Survey"      varchar(1),
    "Ref_desc"    varchar(135),
    "Refuse"      smallint,
    "SciName"     varchar(65),
    "N_Factor"    NUMERIC(4,2),
    "Pro_Factor"  NUMERIC(4,2),
    "Fat_Factor"  NUMERIC(4,2),
    "CHO_Factor"  NUMERIC(4,2)
);
```

That's a pretty literal copy of the description. It's not how I'd design the table

I've used `NUMERIC` arbitrary-precision decimal floating point types for accuracy in non-integer numeric types. If performance is more important than accuracy, you can use `float4` instead.

For relationships, you use `FOREIGN KEY` constraints - just `colname coltype REFERENCES othertable(othercol)` is sufficient to create one.

**Important**: I double quoted the column names to preserve the same name as in the definitions. That means you have to always double quote them when you refer to them, e.g. `SELECT "NDB_No" FROM food_des;` . If you don't want that, just leave off the double quotes - or pick different names. You don't have to stick to the clumsy abbreviated column names they used, and it's quite reasonable to write:

```
CREATE TABLE food_description (
    ndb_no              varchar(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    foodgroup_code      varchar(4) NOT NULL,
    long_description    varchar(200) NOT NULL,
    short_description   varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    common_name         varchar(100),
    manufacturer_name   varchar(65),
```

etc. Similarly, if you're working with Rails, you can convert the table definitions to follow Rails's conventions, especially if you then intend to do the data loading via Rails.

### Loading data

If these were sane, sensible delimited files you could then just load each table using the `psql` command `\copy`, or PgAdmin-III's "import" option.

It is actually CSV, they've just decided to use totally bizarre delimiter and quote chars. Import  via `psql` with:

```
\copy food_des FROM 'FOOD_DES.txt' (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER '^', QUOTE '~');
```

or the equivalent in whatever tool you use to talk to PostgreSQL.

The results are a sensible looking table:

```
craig=> select * from food_des limit 2;
 NDB_No | FdGrp_Cd |         Long_Desc          |        Shrt_Desc         | ComName | ManufacName | Survey | Ref_desc | Refuse | SciName | N_Factor | Pro_Factor | Fat_Factor | CHO_Factor 
--------+----------+----------------------------+--------------------------+---------+-------------+--------+----------+--------+---------+----------+------------+------------+------------
 01001  | 0100     | Butter, salted             | BUTTER,WITH SALT         |         |             | Y      |          |      0 |         |     6.38 |       4.27 |       8.79 |       3.87
 01002  | 0100     | Butter, whipped, with salt | BUTTER,WHIPPED,WITH SALT |         |             | Y      |          |      0 |         |     6.38 |       4.27 |       8.79 |       3.87
(2 rows)
```

Similarly, if using Rails you can use whatever Rails CSV library you want and bulk-load into models.

Comment: This was a fantastic response.  I am going to give it a try.  It is my first attempt at something like this so I may have more questions.  Thank you so much for the thorough answer and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Using the tips from @craig-ringer I've created a script to migrate the original USDA Nutrition Database files to postgreSQL.

Is it very rough at the moment, but should help to get started.

Check it out here:
https://github.com/rlucha/usda-nutrition-database-migration

Answer (score 0):

They have a version of that database for Microsoft access, if you have it you could download to access then convert to MySQL using [Access To MySQL](http://www.bullzip.com/products/a2m/info.php).