# How to insert null values using pg_putcopydata in DBD::Pg?

Tags: perl, postgresql, dbd-pg

I am populating a postgres table with millions of records. In order to speed up the process, I am making use of the pg_putcopydata in DBD:Pg. 
I am following this example :

```
$dbh->do("COPY mytable(flavor, slices) FROM STDIN WITH DELIMITER '~'");
$dbh->pg_putcopydata("Pepperoni~123\n");
$dbh->pg_putcopydata("Mushroom~314\n");
$dbh->pg_putcopydata("Anchovies~6\n");
$dbh->pg_putcopyend();
```

There are records where one of the fields may be emtpy. 
In order to insert empty values, I tried using "undef", "Null", "null", "", "NULL" inside pg_putcopydata. None of them worked.

How do I insert NULL values using pg_putcopydata ?

Comment: See the maual for `COPY` for details on the format. You'll want something like `WITH (DELIMITER '~', NULL '\N')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To include NULLs, you must use in-text insertion, identifying null with a text pattern, e.g. `\N`. This can be specified in the [`COPY` command syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html), e.g.

```
COPY ... FROM ... WITH (DELIMITER '~', NULL '\N')
```

then

```
$dbh->pg_putcopydata("NoSuchFood~\\N\n");
```

(Doubling the backslash to produce a literal backslash sent to Pg).

---

This looks like the [USDA database](http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/) . If so, [here's an answer I wrote earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24792638/398670).