# how to copy data when delimiters are missing in source file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Lets say I have a 4 table in redshift with **4-columns** as :

```
Create Table m.mytab(
 col_1 BIGINT NOT NULL
 col_2 Varchar(200)
 col_3 Varchar(200)
 col_4 INT
);
```

And my Source row file contains data as:

```
 col_1^col_2^col_3^col_4
 myrowdata1^myrowdata2
 myrowdata3^myrowdata4
 .....
```

Here I want to load this data in mytab I tried [copy command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-run-copy.html) of redshift as :

```
copy m.mytab
from 's3://mybucket/folder/fileA.gz '
credentials 'aws_access_key_id=somexxx;aws_secret_access_key=somexxx'
DELIMITER '^'
GZIP
IGNOREHEADER 1
ACCEPTINVCHARS;
```

Since last **2-delimiters** are missing in each row , I am unable to load the data here, can someone suggest me how to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: This wouldn't happen to be https://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/ would it?

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes man I knew that..I m trying to find out way from this. if you can please suggest

Comment: Why'd you obfuscate the data then? Search for "USDA food database postgres"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/24792638/398670. However, last time I looked at the USDA database it didn't have missing trailing delimiters.

Comment: I've posted an answer for a case when col_3 and col_4 are completely missing but then I realized from your data example they might be in every even row of data and col_1 and col_2 are in every odd row... can you confirm that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Try adding `FILLRECORD` parameter to your `COPY` statement

For more information, see [Data Conversion Parameters](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-conversion.html#copy-fillrecord) documentation

2) If all rows are missing col3 and col4 you can just create a staging table with col1 and col2 only, copy data to staging table and then issue

```
ALTER TABLE target_tablename
APPEND FROM staging_tablename
FILLTARGET;
```

This will move data to the `target_tablename` very efficiently (just changing the pointer without writing or deleting data) and take care about missing col3 and col4.

More information about the command: [ALTER TABLE APPEND](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE_APPEND.html)